# update database on session destroy

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, continuous-integration

I need to update a table on session expiration (or close), but this code says `$this->db` is `null?` how I can update the database in session destroy??

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function sess_destroy() {

        $data = array(
            'ip_address' => (string) ''
        );
        $this->db->update($this->tables['users'], $data, array('id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')));

        //call the parent
        parent::sess_destroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Session class doesn't appear to have a DB class inside it. You'll probably need to inject one in via a setter method

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php

OR, if you are using any sort of Observer pattern, add an event listener and trigger the event from inside here.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
        $this->CI->db->update($this->tables['users'], $data, array('id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')));
```